# Eclipse Neon - Project not avaiable for Weblogic

Tags: eclipse, weblogic

in Servers tab, weblogic server, when I click on add/remove resource for add a web project, one of my project is not avaiable!

It is not recognized as a web application project.

I haven't done any configuration, yesterday all worked!

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

In project facets for some reason the "Dynamic Web Module and Java" was unset